# Передача имени выбранного в диалоге файла в приложение

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

У меня программа - Form1. И в ней кнопка, а внизу - TextBox1. И на кнопке действие обзора файлов. Вот код

```
  private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

      OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
      openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
      openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
      openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
      openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

      if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
      {
          //...
      }
  }
```

Что надо в коде дописать, чтобы при выборе файла (тхт) он появился в TEXTBOX1?

Answer (score 1):

[Практическое руководство. Чтение из текстового файла (C++/CLI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y52yxde8.aspx)

Для одной строки:

```
String^ filename = openFileDialog1->FileName;
StreamReader^ sr = gcnew StreamReader(filename);

textBox1->Text = sr->ReadLine();
```

Для нескольких строк предварительно скомпоновать документ.

Comment: Не хочу показаться глупым, но зачем использовать StreamReader? мне всегда казалось, что достаточно просто присвоить openFileDialog1->FileName.

Answer (score 0):

```
openFileDialog1->filename
```